# Why do I end up with a bunch of merge commits?

Tags: git

We work with a release branch, a dev branch, and issue branches.

Our issue branches contain only that issue's commits.

Once a developer completes an issue and submits a pull request, they merge to dev so that it stays updated.

After testing individual issue branches, those branches are then merged into release one-by-one.

Our changelog is then updated on the release branch at this point, and this is then merged back into dev.

The end result is that I have a bunch of merge commits showing up in dev, so it looks like dev is a bunch of commits ahead of release, when really it should be all caught up.  For example:

[image]

At this point, if I merge dev back into release, it shows that they are no longer ahead/behind each other, but no new code was actually brought in.  It's just a bunch of merge commits.

What are we doing wrong that causes this?  Any information about how we can improve this procedure and avoid these would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing anything "wrong" as such; git is just recording exactly what you told it to:

- A commit in git is an immutable object specifying its contents plus metadata. Crucially, this includes the hashes (commit IDs) of the commit's parent(s).
- When you merge two branches together, git creates a commit whose content is the result of the merge, and whose metadata includes the IDs of both parent commits.
- If you merge the same changes in a different order, or even just at different times, the resulting *content* might be the same, but the *metadata* will be different.
- When git compares two branches, it looks first at which commits (with unique hashes) exist in the history of one branch, but not in the history of the other. It then looks at the changes made to content in those commits, and tries to reapply it.

So git is quite rightly telling you that the commits recorded as you merged things into your release branch don't exist on dev, but because they didn't change any content, it can reapply them without changing anything.

In some cases, you can perform a rebase and then a "fast-forward merge" to avoid creating a merge commit (so that the history looks as though all the commits were made directly on one branch, and there is no record of the merge itself). However, that would make things *worse* here, because if you rebase onto the release branch, you'll create a new set of commits which don't exist on dev - you can't "move" a git commit, only copy it and get a new hash.

So if your process works from a QA point of view, you probably have to live with these extra merge commits. There are lots of different merge strategies people have written about that you might want to consider if there are wider problems, though.